# ¿Algún método para saber el nombre (o jerarquía) de la/s clase/s que encapsulan el método que realiza una instancia?

Tags: c#, objeto, class, jerarquía

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de obtener los nombres de la clases (y/o el HashCode del Objeto) que encapsulan a un método que realiza una instancia... pongo un ejemplo por si no me estoy explicando bien y asi se ve mas claro..

```
//------------------------------
public class B
{
   public B()
   {
       List<string> jerarquia = MetodoQueConsigueLaJerarquia();
       
       for(int i=0;i<jerarquia.Count; i++)
       Console.Write(jerarquia[i]);
   }
}
//------------------------------
public class A
{
   B b;
   public A()
   {
      b = new B()
   }
}
//------------------------------
public class MainClass
{
   A a;
   public MainClass()
   {
      a = new A();
   }
}
```

//------------------------------

La salida que me gustaría obtener por pantalla es la siguiente (Nombre o HashCode o ambos)

```
MainClass  313211321
A          646545646
B          978979797
```

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido hacerlo de esta forma. Sin embargo le veo un par de inconvenietes como el echo de que todas las clases deben ser derivadas de la case "Parent" y en todos los constructores hay que pasar como argumento el puntero "this".

Si alguien sabe una forma mas simple de poder hacerlo sin estos inconvenientes que lo publique aquí y le daré la respuesta por valida. Gracias!!

Código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//------------------------------
public class Parent
{
    public System.Object parent = null;
}
//------------------------------
public class ObjectHierarchy
{
    List<System.Object> l;

    public ObjectHierarchy()
    {
        l = new List<System.Object>();
    }
    
    public List<System.Object> GetHierarchy(Parent parents)
    {
        System.Object parent = parents.parent;
        l.Add(parents);

        if (parent != null)           
        GetHierarchy( (Parent)parent);           
        
        return l;
    }
}
//------------------------------
public class C : Parent
{
    public C(System.Object parent = null)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        ObjectHierarchy o = new ObjectHierarchy();
        List<System.Object> l = o.GetHierarchy((Parent)this.parent);

        for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n " + i +" "+ l[i] + " " + l[i].GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
//------------------------------
public class B : Parent
{
    public B(System.Object parent=null)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        C c = new C(this);
    }
}
//------------------------------
public class A : Parent
{
    public A(System.Object parent=null)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        B b = new B(this);
    }
}
//------------------------------
public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       A a = new A();
    }
}
//------------------------------
//compilar
//C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\ejmpo>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe jerarquia.cs
//------------------------------
//Salida
0 B 46104728
1 A 12289376
```